# Export DataTables to Excel Files in .NET using OpenXML and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, openxml

i am exporting 2 datatables to excel, with the openxml third party tool, but i am facing error for applying borders to the tables or i am unable to apply borders to the both tables, i tried diff ways but no luck.

```
            private void ApplyBorders(Row row, Stylesheet stylesheet, uint styleIndex)
    {
        foreach (Cell cell in row.Elements<Cell>())
        {
            if (cell.StyleIndex != null)
            {
                int styleIndexValue = (int)cell.StyleIndex.Value;
                if (styleIndexValue < stylesheet.CellFormats.Count)
                {
                    CellFormat cellFormat = (CellFormat)stylesheet.CellFormats.ElementAt(styleIndexValue);
                    cellFormat.BorderId = styleIndex;
                    cellFormat.ApplyBorder = true;
                }
              
            }
            else
            {
                CellFormat cellFormat = new CellFormat { BorderId = styleIndex, ApplyBorder = true };
                stylesheet.CellFormats.Append(cellFormat);
                cell.StyleIndex = (uint)stylesheet.CellFormats.Count - 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What line is giving error and what is error?  This has nothing to do with tables.  You are trying to format a cell in an excel worksheet.  You may be indexing outside the array.

Comment: Create an Excel spreadsheet that is representative of the one you are trying to programatically create. Then use [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5) to see the structure of the Excel spreadsheet. Alternatively, you can change the extension  from `.xlsx` to `.zip` and then unzip the file.

Comment: I agree with above idea. In fact OFTEN  better to create the Excel sheet with all the fancy formatting, colors, and layout. Use that "source" sheet as your template, and thus your code ONLY has to export/add rows to that sheet. So, then all of the messy formatting code is not required - its in the Excel sheet that you use over and over. So, include the fancy formatted excel sheet as part of your project, load it, add the data and rows and then save to a new sheet.  Thus code behind will ONLY have to add rows, but not have boatloads of color and formatting code. And with template changes easy.

Comment: I prefer to use EPPlus to create or read excel files, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/writing-to-excel-sheet-using-epplus-in-c-sharp/